# Exporting a d3.js overlay on top of a Bing Map using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, bing, html2canvas

Has anyone attempted to use html2canvas with Bing Maps. I have been able to get html2canvas to work with google maps but I now need to get it to work for Bing Maps. When I attempt to export my svg with is a d3.js overlay ontop of a Bing Map it looks like this?

[image]

My html2canvas export code is as follows:

```
 html2canvas($svg, {
 proxy: "",
 useCORS: true,
 background: "#E8F0F6",
 onrendered: function (canvas) {

            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.download = name;
            a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();


        },
        width: 450,
        height: 700,

    });
```

Comment: I am working with Highcharts and try converting it to image with html2canvas.